# Distinct MySQL  query returning all records

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table, `user_quotes`, with the fields `quotes_id`, `quotes_user`, `quotes_desc`, `quotes_date`, `quotes_status`, and `quotes_location`. In this `quotes_user` allows duplication entries. When I execute my query I am trying to avoid duplication entries of `quotes_user`. So I executed the query like this,

```
select distinct quotes_user from user_quotes;
```

This query returns only the `quotes_user` field. How can I retrieve all other records using `distinct quotes_user`.

I have tried with these following,

```
select distinct quotes_user, quotes_desc, quotes_date, quotes_status from user_quotes;
```

It's not avoiding the duplication of quotes_user.

If I use,

```
select distinct quotes_user, * from user_quotes;
```

I am getting mysql error,

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `user_quotes`.

How can I fetch all records using select distinct of a single column in a same table? I am storing the email address in the field. The datatype is `varchar`.

Note: please don't suggest me other types like group by or other. I need to know how I can retrieve the records by only using `distinct`.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve 1 row of quote for each quotes_user? Like the most recent quote for each user, or the first one, something like that? Or do you want a count of quotes or an average quote value for each quotes_user?

Comment: @Dale I want to avoid the duplication of quotes_user. may be the result will be vary based on the quotes_user. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what has already been said, it should be stressed that the `DISTINCT` keyword **can't** give you distinct results for an individual column when you're selecting multiple columns.  You will get distinct *rows* of, in your case, 4 columns.  What you're observing is the expected, standard behaviour of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: ok. Can u elaborate with my example how can i achieve all records by using disitinct in any other way ? by using join like ?

Comment: I can't really think of anyway to achieve what you want using `DISTINCT`.  This can be done very easily with `GROUP BY`.  Why are you so attached to using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: oh.. fine. there is no reason why i am looking for this distinct question. As i got the result by using GROUP BY, i just want to know how can i get the results using distinct. If some one provide me some links or tutorials to learn in deep about distinct, will be helpful to me. thanks.

Comment: I got the results by using Distinct, exactly what i am looking for. check out the Quassnoi's Answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/sql-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column . Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to retrieve the other fields, but you haven't specified **how** SQL is to know **which values** to retrieve for the other fields, for each distinct value of `quotes_user`.

To show you want I mean, consider this example:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| quotes_user | email_address |
+-------------+---------------+
| user1       | email1        |
| user1       | email2        |
| user2       | email3        |
| user2       | email4        |
| user2       | email5        |
| user3       | email6        |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Now, if you **just** wanted `quotes_user`, the output would obviously be:

```
+-------------+
| quotes_user |
+-------------+
| user1       |
| user2       |
| user3       |
+-------------+
```

But if you wanted the other fields as well, you'd need to decide whether, for example, to have `email1` or `email2` for the `user1` row.

Perhaps what you want is to **concatenate** the values of the other fields together. In that case, I would suggest using the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function with `GROUP BY quotes_user`.

I'm not sure why you want to avoid using `GROUP BY`, though. Perhaps if you could explain that, we could help more.

Comment: hey, did you write those ascii tables by hand or is there a tool available to generate them?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I got the result when i have tried with group by. but in the same way why cant i get the results i have tried with distinct. how can i achieve the same result, done using group by with the distinct.

Comment: @Dale Halliwell: I just did them by hand (with the help of a bit of cut-and-paste, of course). I wouldn't be surprised if there was a tool do them, though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `quotes_user` should be a foreign key like `user_id` to presumably your users table. You could then query `user_quotes` by `user_id` returning all the quotes for that user. Your front end could then format all the quotes for each user nicely, it doesn't really sound like a MySql issue.